# Jacoco complains about unlikely missing branch coverage

Tags: java, kotlin, jacoco

I'm using Gradle 6.3 and Jacoco to compile, test and show coverage report. But I fail to understand why it complains there is "1 of 2 branches missed", there is no branch at all:

[image: 1 of 2 branches missed]

Here is the complete Kotlin data class:

```kotlin
data class ListNode<T>(var value: T, var next: ListNode<T>?) {

    override fun hashCode(): Int = value.hashCode()

}
```

If somehow there are branches behind the scene, what are they and how do I cover them?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are actually two branches in the bytecode and here is why.

You are using the extension `hashCode()` on `Any?` since the `T`'s upper bound is `Any?`, not `Any`. This extension is implemented like so:

```kotlin
public inline fun Any?.hashCode(): Int = this?.hashCode() ?: 0
```

This means that in the bytecode, your call to `value.hashCode()` is replaced with `value?.hashCode() ?: 0`.

In your test you are covering only the case in which `value` is not null probably, so the branch `?: 0` isn't covered.

You have two solutions here until JaCoCo won't support `inline` functions:

- cover also the other branch testing a `ListNode` using a `null` `T`.
- use `Any` as the `T`'s upper bound:

```
data class ListNode<T: Any>(var value: T, var next: ListNode<T>?)
```

Comment: Thank you Giorgio, for such a clean answer!

Comment: @adamsmith No problem!

Answer (score 0):

A `data class` in Kotlin has default auto-generated methods (`equals`, `toString`, `hashCode`, getters, setters). In this case we're talking about `equals`. It is not visible in the code of `class ListNode`, but its JVM bytecode definitely contains `equals`, `toString`, etc.

Jacoco is mostly targeted for **Java** **Co**de **Co**verage, so this situation, probably, may be treated as a Jacoco's incorrect handling of generated methods in Kotlin. If you wish - commit an [issue](https://github.com/jacoco/jacoco/issues) for the project maintainers.

Anyways, to avoid Jacoco warnings for this particular case, just look at the code in the report (lines 17,18,.. up to the end of the `equals` method):

1. temporarily copy contents of generated `equals` method to the `ListNode` (just for own convenience)
2. increase the code coverage to the needed level
3. erase the `equals` method
4. code coverage remain as it was on step (2), because `equals` remains the same (but now it is created implicitly)